# How to force interpretation as keyword instead of alias on command line?

Tags: bash

I have

```
alias time='/usr/bin/time -v'
```

configured in my bash environment.

However, I sometimes need an access to keyword time for some one-liners such as

```
(expensive-command1 & expensive-command2 & time wait); something-that-requires-prev-commands-to-be-complete
```

Where the `wait` should obviously wait for both `expensive-command1` and `expensive-command2` to complete and the keyword time is able to measure the time taken.

However, when I have alias time pointing to actual binary I get following error instead:

```
/usr/bin/time: cannot run wait: No such file or directory
```

**How to force interpretation `keyword` for the `time` in command above?** I know that if I run `unalias time` before running above line it works but then my alias is gone for that shell.

I also know that if I wanted to go from keyword to actual binary, I could use syntax `(cmd1 & cmd2 & command time wait)`. And if I needed built-in command I could use syntax `(cmd1 & cmd2 & builtin time wait)`. However, the `time` needed here is not command nor builtin. It's a `keyword` but I cannot figure out how to get the above one-liner to be interpreted as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Bash version 4.4, there's no nice way to force interpretation as keyword instead of alias. **For workarounds, see answer by oguz ismail.** In short, all workarounds create alternate name for the original keyword behavior and then you have to always use the alternate instead of the correct keyword.

For now, it seems that **the best way to proceed is to consider all bash keywords as reserved words** and never ever define any alias with identical name. This is the solution that I'm personally using.

Answer (score 2):

Define a function like below before the line where alias `time` is defined in your bashrc.

```
_time() { time "$@"; }
```

Then you can use `_time` whenever you need the keyword `time`.

```
$ _time() { time "$@"; }
$ alias time='echo foo'
$ time ls
foo ls
$ _time ls
.bash_history .bashrc

real    0m0.024s
user    0m0.010s
sys     0m0.000s
```

The manual explains why this works as follows.

> Aliases are expanded when a function definition is read, not when the function is executed, because a function definition is itself a command.

---

In an environment where you don't have permission to change bashrc, you can do:

```
$ shopt -u expand_aliases
$ _time() { time "$@"; }
$ shopt -s expand_aliases
```

and get the same functionality.

Comment: That's a possible workaround assuming you can run code before setting the alias. One could also do `TIME_ALIAS=$(alias time); unalias time; sleep 1 & time wait; source <(echo "$TIME_ALIAS")` as a workaround. That's pretty long to type for a one-liner.

Comment: Combining the function workaround with unalias workaround in above comment allow calling keyword time via function even if time has been aliased before current execution context.

Comment: Yes, I understood your response. I'm considering more generic cases where you're given a shell and have to work within the current environment. In that case, it's already too late to start configuring the bash environment.

Comment: I think it's much better not to override the `time` if it cannot be easily restored in `bash`. In long run, it's much easier to use another alias name if this use case cannot be easily fixed.

Comment: One would expect `sleep 1 & sleep 1 & keyword time wait` to work even if `time` is an alias but that is not valid `bash` syntax.

Comment: @Miko Okay. *Combining the function workaround with unalias workaround in above comment allow calling keyword time via function even if time has been aliased before current execution context.* This is not true, though. Once you define the time alias, the word **time** in function definitions to come will be replaced with the aliased string. So that's not a workaround. In a case where I can't make changes on bashrc, I'd temporarily disable alias expansion using `shopt -u expand_aliases`.

Comment: But I agree that handling of aliases is a mess, not only in bash, but all shells.

Comment: Following works but is far from nice for interactive use even if `alias time='/usr/bin/time -v'` has already been run: `TIME_ALIAS=$(alias time); unalias time; _time() { time "$@"; }; source <(echo "$TIME_ALIAS"); sleep 1 & _time wait` but it will leak function `_time` so next time you must not defined _time.

Comment: @Mikko Yes, I just added a similar one to the answer. Yet I'm not following you, I really didn't get what your concern is.

Comment: I agree that doing via `shopt -u expand_aliases` is much nicer.

Comment: @Mikko maybe you should file a feature request/bug report to bug-bash@gnu.org